# Resignation function invalidates the index value of other employee objects stored in a list

Tags: python

I have a class `ResignationSystem`.  I also have an `Employee` and `Company` class.

```py
class ResignationSystem:
    def accept_resignation(self, employee):
            self.employee_list.pop(employee.employee_num)

    def resignation_from_employee(self, employee):
        resign = self.accept_resignation(employee)
        if resign:
            self.employee_del_attr(employee)

        else:
            print("Resignation declined.")
        
    def employee_del_attr(self, employee):
        del employee.company
        del employee.salary
        del employee.employee_num
        employee.has_job = False
```

```py
class Company(ResignationSystem):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.minimum_hiring_grades_percent = 90
        self.employee_max_leaves = 30
        self.name = name

    employee_list = []
```

Employee Class

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, number, grades):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.working_days = 300
        self.bonus_percent = 30
        self.has_job = False
        self.grades_percent_average = grades
        self.employee_num = None

    def resign_from_company(self):
        self.company.resignation_from_employee(self)
```

Each employee has a unique `employee_num` which is the index of its dictionary in the `employee_list`. When popping the employee dictionary from `employee_list` of `Company`, the `employee_num` of all employees ahead of the popped employee are invalidated. Is there anyway I can avoid this, or then change all `employee_num`

An example of what the employee_list may look like:

```
[
{'name': 'Rob', 'number': 9606239371, 'working_days': 300, 'bonus_percent': 30, 'has_job': True, 'grades_percent_average': 90, 'employee_num': 0, 'available_leaves': 30, 'salary_dollars': 90000, 'company': 'EY'},

 {'name': 'Steve', 'number': 9980083117, 'working_days': 300, 'bonus_percent': 30, 'has_job': True, 'grades_percent_average': 91, 'employee_num': 1, 
'available_leaves': 30, 'salary_dollars': 91000, 'company': 'EY'}
]
```

If:

```
rob.resign_from_company
```

Then, the dictionary of rob, which is at index value 0, is popped. But, the `employee_num` of steve now doesn't correspond to its index value. This causes errors in other functions which aren't required for the scope of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary instead of a list to store your employees, using `employee_num` as the keys of that dictionary.

your employee_list would look like:

```py
{
    0 : {'name': 'Rob', 'number': 9606239371, 'working_days': 300, 'bonus_percent': 30, 'has_job': True, 'grades_percent_average': 90, 'employee_num': 0, 'available_leaves': 30, 'salary_dollars': 90000, 'company': 'EY'},
    1 : {'name': 'Steve', 'number': 9980083117, 'working_days': 300, 'bonus_percent': 30, 'has_job': True, 'grades_percent_average': 91, 'employee_num': 1, 'available_leaves': 30, 'salary_dollars': 91000, 'company': 'EY'}
}
```

Alternatively you could look at "real" databases.

Comment: Hey, thanks this works, I guess databases are the best, but I'm relatively new to python, and want to learn more about ways that are already in python before moving to stuff outside of this

Comment: SQLite is inside python :) Jokes aside your approach is right, you can worry about databases when you really need them.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there was an inbuilt database in python. Thanks for letting me know